# How can I find which cells in a column (or at least the first one) are greater than a threshold in a LibreOffice spreadsheet.?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, spreadsheet

I have a LibreOffice spreadsheet (actually a CSV file open in spreadsheet).

It has several columns.

Something like this:

```
1,3,4
2,4,6
1,3,4
10,3,4
2,4,5
0,3,4
-10,3,4
```

I want to find in a column (say the first column) where are values with absolute value greater than a threshold.

For example if the threshold is 9 the above table would have rows 4(10) and 7(-10) as the answer.

I have attempted doing this:

```
=MATCH(1, A89723:A89731>1, 0)
```

But it doesn’t do what I want.

How can I have this in a formula?

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following formula in cell D1 and fill down.

```
=IF(ABS(A1)>9;"Row " &ROW()&" ("&A1&")";"")
```

Result:

```
Row 4 (10)


Row 7 (-10)
```

Comment: Ok, so that would give me one more column and then visually inspect. mmm the problem is that I have many rows, and visually inspect seems not that feasible. I was hoping for something that gives me a list of indexes but I guess it is not practical in a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way to achieve what you want but you will need a 'helper' column (can be hidden) and a results column.

The **helper** column formula is `=IF(ABS(A1)>9,ROW(A1),"")` where **A1** is the first cell being tested and **9** is the comparison number.

The **results** column formula is `=IFERROR(SMALL($D$1:$D$25,ROW(E2)-ROW($E$1)),"")` where **D** is the helper column and **E** is the results column.